# How to close exec() function command or close command run by exec() function?

Tags: php, command, exec, wkhtmltopdf

```
$cmd_pdf = 'xvfb-run --wait=0******************';
exec($cmd_pdf, $output_pdf);
```

How can I close this command as it is showing "Excessive resource usage:" error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem where wkhtmltopdf hangs indefinitely, so I run it with the [timeout](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) utility, which allows you to set a time limit on execution.

```
<?
$htmlFilePath = 'myfile.html';
$pdfFilePath = 'myfile.pdf';

/*
 * Current version of wkhtmltopdf has some deep down nasty bug that causes it to hang
 * indefinitely at random on linux. Let's add some retry logic to work around that.
 */
$output = array();
$timeoutStatusCode = 124;//Timeout utility will return 124 as the exit code if it does in fact time out
$timoutTime = '15s'; //In prod, most PDFs seem to take < 1.5 seconds, but let's be generous.
$exitStatus = null;
$maxIterations = 15; //I've seen nine in a row fail, mostly only takes one retry
$currIteration = 0;

$shellArgs = '--use-xserver --viewport-size 1280x1024';//...
do
{
    exec('export DISPLAY=":0";timeout '.$timoutTime.' wkhtmltopdf '.$shellArgs.' '.$htmlFilePath.' '.$pdfFilePath, $output, $exitStatus);

    $currIteration++;
} while($exitStatus==$timeoutStatusCode && $currIteration<$maxIterations);

/*
 * Make sure PDF creation was successful before post processing. Throw an exception if generation failed
 */
if($exitStatus==$timeoutStatusCode)
{
    throw new Exception('PDF Generation failed for '.$htmlFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, I used timeout but not working.

$timoutTime = '120s';
$cmd_pdf = 'xvfb-run --wait=0 timeout '.$timoutTime.' wkhtmltopdf -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 -q --page-height ' . $page_height . ' --page-width ' . $page_width . ' -s A4 ' . basename($html_file) . ' ' . basename($pdf_file);
exec($cmd_pdf, $output_pdf);

Comment: timeout is a command that wraps other commands, so it has to be first in the chain. Look at the docs for it.